# One- to Two-Week Game Competition

Tags: competition

Ludum Dare is great, except it's only 48-72 hours (depending on your flavour). Is there any particular (good) competition that gives you 1-2 weeks to develop? I don't usually get enough time to put significant effort in 2-3 days.

**Edit:** I'm using .NET. It must be open to .NET (Silverlight, preferably) games.

Comment: Argh, I swear I remeber one that's a week long. I can't remember it :(

Comment: Are you using Python? If so, I could answer with PyWeek :)

Comment: Nope, using .NET. Experimental Gameplay is probably the one you wanted.

Comment: No, I think I was thinking of the Ludum Jam one. Meh, I was **sure** of a week long thing.

Comment: Ludum Jam is 3 days. Or I would have gone with that :)

Comment: One thing to note about Ludum Dare: the monthly miniLDs usually have *very* relaxed rules, and there's nothing wrong with spreading out development time over a week.

Comment: @thedaian that's what I'm going for. But I prefer not to wait for those one-off contests. Hence my question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Two major ones I know of are the [Seven Day Roguelike](http://roguebasin.roguelikedevelopment.org/index.php?title=7DRL) Competition and [Pyweek](http://www.pyweek.org/).

[The Something Awful Forums](http://forums.somethingawful.com/) also has a month long gamedev competition, starting in July.  You can form teams, but you or someone on your team has to have an account there.

The [Experimental Gameplay Project](http://experimentalgameplay.com/) also has month long competitions where you're only allowed to spend a week on development.  Each month there's a different theme.

[TIGSource forums](http://forums.tigsource.com/) also occasionally do month long competitions, though they seem to happen somewhat rarely.